# How can I pass todo list object to test file to override initial state?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, use-context

This is pretty common problem with less solved results here in the web. I tried to test my Statistics component which uses `useContext` hook. As test runs in isolated mode it catches always empty array and I couldn't pass my todo list object.

I am trying to run test but it fails

```
FAIL src/components/Statistics/__test__/Statistics.test.js (5.23 s)
  ● Testing Statistics Component › should return valid complete amount and due tasks count

    expect(element).toHaveTextContent()

    Expected element to have text content:
      3
    Received:
      0

      36 |
      37 |     const completedCount = screen.getByTestId("completed-count");
    > 38 |     expect(completedCount).toHaveTextContent(3);
         |                            ^
      39 |
      40 |     const dueTaskCount = screen.getByTestId("due-todo");
      41 |     expect(dueTaskCount).toHaveTextContent(1);
```

My context code

```
export const TodoContext = createContext(null);

function TodoContextProvider(props) {
  const initialState = []
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {props.children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default TodoContextProvider;
```

My Statistics component

```
function Statistics() {
  const { state } = useContext(TodoContext);

  const completedTodo = todos?.filter((item) => item.complete === true);
  const dueTodos = todos?.filter((item) => new Date(item.due) < new Date());

  return (
    <Row className="m-1 p-4">
      <Col>
        <h2 className="text-primary text-center">My ToDo Statistics</h2>
        <p className="text-center">
          Completed: <span data-testid="completed-count">{completedTodo?.length}</span> |
          Due: <span data-testid="due-todo">{dueTodos?.length}</span>
        </p>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

export default Statistics;
```

And at last my test file for Statistics

```
describe("Testing Statistics Component", () => {
  it("should return valid complete amount and due tasks count", () => {
    render(
      <TodoContextProvider>
        <Statistics />
      </TodoContextProvider>
    );

    const completedCount = screen.getByTestId("completed-count");
    expect(completedCount).toHaveTextContent(3);

    const dueTaskCount = screen.getByTestId("due-todo");
    expect(dueTaskCount).toHaveTextContent(1);
  });
});
```

> Here is todo list items

```
const todos = [
  {
    todo: "Take a note",
    due: "2022-04-01",
    id: 1648874401775,
    complete: true,
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    todo: "Brush teeth",
    due: "2022-04-13",
    id: 1648874401776,
    complete: true,
    order: 2,
  },
  {
    todo: "Go to bed",
    due: "2022-04-23",
    id: 1648874401777,
    complete: true,
    order: 3,
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyze your code. Let's quickly run the main problems which I detected.

1. `TodoContextProvider` is not extendable. It's strongly encapsulated.
2. In Statistics test file you did not provide (`todos`) state values. Where context does need to accept it?
3. For note - always libraries which need to wrap all your app create custom render. As in example below.

```js
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { todoContext } from "../context/TodoContext";

const customRender = (ui, { providerProps, ...renderOptions }) => {
  return render(
    <todoContext.Provider {...providerProps}>{ui}</todoContext.Provider>,
    renderOptions
  );
};

export { customRender as render };
```

[**Source**](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context/)

I create additional file for testing utils. Named as `testing-library-utils.jsx`. And import render from there.

```
import { screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import Statistics from "../Statistics";
import { render } from "../../../test-utils/testing-library-utils";

const todos = [
  {
    todo: "Take a note",
    due: "2022-04-01",
    id: 1648874401775,
    complete: true,
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    todo: "Brush teeth",
    due: "2022-04-13",
    id: 1648874401776,
    complete: true,
    order: 2,
  },
  {
    todo: "Go to bed",
    due: "2022-04-23",
    id: 1648874401777,
    complete: true,
    order: 3,
  },
];

describe("Testing Statistics Component", () => {
  it("should return valid complete amount and due tasks count", () => {

    const providerProps = {
      value: {
        state: todos,
      },
    };

    render(<Statistics />, { providerProps });

    const completedCount = screen.getByTestId("completed-count");
    waitFor(() => expect(completedCount).toHaveTextContent(3)).then();
  });
});
```

In my case, all the tests are passed.
I recommend you learn of testing concept in react before starting to write any tests.